# How do I have menu linked content not on main page?

Tags: nodes

My web site is the first drupal site I have made.  And after I made it, I left it to do other work -- like write the blogs for the site.  I cannot remember how I set up the content pages that link to menu selection that do not appear as content on the main page.

The best way to explain what I am talking about is with a screen capture.  I have added menu items to my main menu.  I do not remember how I did it in the past.  I want to add content and have it linked to the main menu (this option is available to me when I create the content) but I do not want them to appear as stories on the main page.

The circled areas in this screen shot shows the menu item I just added and the corresponding item on the main page that I do not want to be there.  How do I remove it from the main page?

I am thinking that perhaps I should not have added it as a "content" but something else? If so, what and how?

http://www.arguemax.com/images/problems/12-6-2015/Capture_001.PNG

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Content, be sure to uncheck "Promoted to front page" in the option menu shown at the bottom, under **Published options**. See image.

[image]

If you want this option by default for a specific content type (for example, for **Articles**) you will need to go to **Structure > Content types** and edit that content type's **Publishing options** to uncheck **Promoted to front page**. This will become the default option when you create a new Article.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue edit the content and just you need to unchecked the **promoted to font page** options under **publishing options** tab at the end of edit page.

Comment: To fixed it for all content of any content types do as @argiepiano mentioned. It's better to unchecked this option whenever you create new content types.